# Dynamic parameter in href option in Aurelia Routing config.map

Tags: aurelia

This seems like a really simple issue, but it's driving me crazy...

Does anyone know how I can specify a dynamic **:id** parameter in the href routing configuration option?

The following unfortunately doesn't work:

```
    config.map([
        // ... default parameterless routing here
        {
            route:[':id/request'],
            moduleId:'processes/bdd/request/request',
            name:'Request', title:'Request', href:`#/bdd/request/${id}/request`, settings:{type:'Request', icon:''}, nav:true,
        },
        {
            route:[':id/requestAuth'],
            moduleId:'processes/bdd/request/requestauthorization',
            name:'RequestAuthorization', title:'Request Authorization', href:`#/bdd/request/${id}/requestAuth`, settings:{type:'Request', icon:''}, nav:true,
        },
        // ... some additional mappings here
    ]);
```

Answer (score 5):

The `href` property is static. If you want to generate a route for a link using this route, you could use the `route-href` custom attribute like this:

```
 route-href="route: request; params.bind: { id: someProp }"
```

Note that I changed the route name to be camelCase (all lowercase since it is one word here) to match the route naming convention.

Comment: But if I remove the **href** attribute in the route configuration? If I attempt to remove it, I get the following error: `ERROR [app-router] Error: Invalid route config for ":id?/requestAuth" : dynamic routes must specify an "href:" to be included in the navigation model.`

Comment: That's because you have the `nav: true` property set. If you aren't planning on using this route in some form of nav bar or something like that, then remove that and the router will stop complaining.

Comment: But what if I do want to use it in a nav  bar?

Comment: Then you will need to specify a static `href` value for the route. Think about how that value will be used. It's being used to build a nav-bar. Links in a nav-bar are static, not dynamic. You would have to come up with what a "default" value for "id" is for that route. If it doesn't make sense to have a default value, then that route shoudln't be part of the nav bar.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar use case and I was able to get this to work by adding a pipeline step to the router that alters the config on the fly.

My use case may be a little different in that I only want the item to appear in the nav bar when the route is active -- say I have routes `/abc`, `/def/:id`, and `/ghi` -- when the active route is ABC or GHI, only those items will appear in the nav bar, but when the active route is DEF, it should appear in the nav bar, and clicking it should lead to the same DEF ID you're currently looking at. So my route configuration includes a setting that indicates the route should only appear in the nav bar when it's the active route.

Here are the interesting parts of my actual configureRouter function:

```
configureRouter(config, router) {
  config.addPreActivateStep(Preactivate); // explained below
  config.map([
    // some routes
    { route: 'patients/:patientId', name: 'patient-master',
      moduleId: 'patients-and-cases/patient-master/patient-master',
      title: 'Patient', nav: true, settings: { renderOnlyWhenActive: true },
      href: '#' // it doesn't matter what this is
    },
    // more routes
  ]);
}
```

And here is the `Preactivate` class that sets the href on preactivate:

```
class Preactivate {
  run(routingContext, next) {
    routingContext.config.href = routingContext.fragment;
    return next();
  }
}
```

If, unlike me, you want this to display in a nav bar all the time, this will still work -- the href will simply remain set to the last thing it was set to when the route was active. In that case you'd probably want to initialize it to some default value that makes sense.